# Gnome Online Accounts - CVE-2013-0240

Tags: gnome, security

I'm in a discussion with Cybersecurity Team on the company that I work. I'm trying dealing to allow again this integration in our environment.
The Cyber guys expose this [CVE](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-0240/) detail. I search on the web if this had been fixed, looked too in [Gitlab Online Accounts repository](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-online-accounts), but not found news about it.

Someone know if this vulnerability it was fixed?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Doesn't the description tell you: "Gnome Online Accounts (GOA) 3.4.x, 3.6.x before 3.6.3, and 3.7.x before 3.7.5," In Ubuntu 20.04 current version is 3.36.0, so well beyond. This CVE is from 2013...

Comment: Exactly, don't tell nothing about the fix and yep this it was reported at 2013...it feels like it's abandoned

Comment: Fix long released: https://ubuntu.com/security/cve-2013-0240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu  20.04 isn't affected, this vulnerability has been patched.

Affected releases:  Ubuntu 12.10, Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 11.10

[USN-1779-1: GNOME Online Accounts vulnerability](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-1779-1)

Comment: Thanks bro! I get your reply + the comments directly in my question and I guess that I have sufficient information to allow again the Gnome Online Accounts.